# Performing String Manipulation on result of \cite{}

Tags: macros, citing, strings

I would like to perform some string manipulation (using the `xstring` package) on the result of a `\cite{}` (the bib package is given to me, and wouldn't allow what I want to do without a major rewrite). However, I can't find a way to assign the *result* of the `\cite{}` to a variable. `\edef` doesn't work, nor does `\protected@edef`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to tex.stackexchange! You can format inline code in your question with backticks (`).

Comment: The `\cite` macro is not expandable, and so you cannot do what you want in the way you want. Perhaps you might explain a bit more what manipulation you need to carry out?

Comment: I would like to take the result, such as "[Author et al. 2005]" and transform it to "Author et al. [2005]". For instance, natbib supports this directly (via `\citet`), however, the one I have to use (for a publication) doesn't allow this (it's not using `\citeauthoryear` internally).

Comment: Maybe you want to instead look at the the aux or bbl files?

Comment: If it is for a publication, maybe you shouldn't tamper too much with the style of citations? (the journal might want uniformity)

Comment: @Matthew: I suppose I could read the .bbl file and parse it, but that seems overly complicated. @Bruno: actually I am not tampering with it, I'm just trying to make the given style more easily accessible. Instead of having to do "...and the work by Author et al.\ `\shortcite{author1998}`...", I simply want to do "...and the work by `\citet{author1998}`...". (Note: `\shortcite` gives the year only).

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding your comment correctly, what you really want is the output of `\citet` but without the parentheses around the year. In that case, you want to use `\citealt`.

If you want a different behavior, you should add more details.